# Checking if some infinite trigonometric sum is convergent

Tags: trigonometry, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

How can I check if this sum (on the natural numbers) is convergent?$$\sum_{n\mod90\neq0}\frac{\tan^2n}{n^3}$$

Comment: I'm assuming you intend for the argument to be interpreted in degrees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the argument is in degrees, this converges since $\tan (x-180)=\tan x$. Thus there is an $M>0$ such that for $n$ not a multiple of $90$ we have
$$\tan^2 n\leq M$$
Thus the series converges by comparison to
$$\sum \frac M{n^3}$$

Comment: I think you can safely say this $M$ is $\tan(89°)$ But then in the sum, it would be $M^2$.

Comment: @zwim Thanks, I fixed it. I think it's probably not useful to know that it's $\tan 89$, so I'll leave that out.